# Tracts in a Place from Census API

Tags: us-census

Using the [US Census Decennial Census API](http://www.census.gov/data/developers/data-sets/decennial-census-data.html), is it possible to get a list of all the Census tracts that are part of a Census place.

Comment: http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/baf_description.html may or may not be helpful. Note that these files assign blocks to named places, not tracts. It's possible that a single tract can be split across multiple place names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with just the Decennial Census API, but a solution can be constructed with the Census's [TIGERweb services](https://tigerweb.geo.census.gov/).

In sketch, use TIGERweb REST service to get the geometry of a place, and then use that geometry with another TIGERweb REST service to get a list of tracts that intersect with a place, and then use the Decennial Census API to look up information about those tracts.

This is the road I took in this [python library](https://github.com/datamade/census_area) that allows queries of tracts, blockgroups, and blocks by place (or other arbitrary geometries).